# Why eclipse creates two class files for Python?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm new in Python but loving it.

I'm using Eclipse for IDE, but confused why it creates two classes, Please take a look at screenshot

[image]

Can you please tell what it is used for?

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: these are to tell python that com and mypython are packages. see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 0):

Placing `__init__.py` file in a folder simply tells the interpreter/IDE that it contain(may contain) python scrips.

Now in the mentioned scenario, eclipse placed two `__init__.py` files but one for/in `com` folder and one for `myPythonProject`. Which means both folders contain(may contain) python files.